# Laravel Database notification - group by post id and type

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I cannot figure out one problem with Database notification in Laravel.
I wish to show user notifications like Facebook. For example: "User X, Y and 2 other people commented your photo". My database structure looks like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|                  id                  |             type             | notifiable_type | notifiable_id |                        data             | read_at |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 6d57d30c-419c-4f22-9aaa-f6bb22354887 | App\Notifications\NewComment | App\Models\User |             1 | {"userId":4,"commentId":42,"albumId":3} |         | 2020-01-29 18:00:10 | 2020-01-29 18:03:15 |
| 7d57d30c-419c-4f22-9aaa-f6bb22354887 | App\Notifications\NewComment | App\Models\User |             1 | {"userId":4,"commentId":42,"albumId":3} |         | 2020-01-29 18:00:15 | 2020-01-29 18:03:15 |
| 8d57d30c-419c-4f22-9aaa-f6bb22354887 | App\Notifications\NewComment | App\Models\User |             1 | {"userId":5,"commentId":42,"albumId":2} |         | 2020-01-29 18:03:15 | 2020-01-29 18:03:15 |
| 9d57d30c-419c-4f22-9aaa-f6bb22354887 | App\Notifications\NewComment | App\Models\User |             1 | {"userId":4,"commentId":42,"albumId":2} |         | 2020-01-29 18:02:15 | 2020-01-29 18:03:15 |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I can't figure out how to group by `type` and `albumId` (within the `data` column.) Can you help me please? I still overwriting User model method:

```php
public function getNotificationsAttribute()
{
    $notifications = $this->notifications();
    $notifications->groupBy('type', 'data->albumId')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    return $notifications;
}
```

Comment: is your `data` field's type json? why so many double quote?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, data field is type text. It's default data type when create notification table with artisan (`php artisan notifications:table`) Edit - double quote is probably my mistake. When I export table, i choose TSV format, which add double quote. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be very challenging to do this with the query builder (even more so since this isn't a JSON column) but if you're working with a collection, [`groupBy()` can take a callback function](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-groupby), so it's quite simple to do something like this:

```
public function getNotificationsAttribute()
{
    return $this
        ->notifications()
        ->get()
        ->groupBy("type"),
        ->groupBy(function($data) {
            return $data["albumId"];
        })
        ->orderBy("created_at", "desc");
}
```

This assumes that the Eloquent model is configured to cast the column as an array.

```
protected $casts = ["data" => "array"];
```